# jQueryMobile Dynamic Pages - Events triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, navigation

I'm working on a jQueryMobile website that let people order products. There are dynamic pages (such as product page) and I have some events in there (that calculates the total, refreshes the ingredient list, etc).

The first time you enter a product page everything works fine, however after you add the product in the cart and get back to another product, everything triggers once again. So for example if you add 10 items in the cart, for the 10th item, everything (including ajax calls) is triggered 10 times.

I recorded a video here: http://www.screenr.com/Ew5H so you can see exactly the issue.

The website url is: http://m2.pizzaboy.y11.in/

The JS file is here: http://m2.pizzaboy.y11.in/assets/js/main.js

I'm using:

```
$( document ).delegate("#page-product", "pageinit", function() {
    //stuff here
});
```

to trigger all actions on the product page.

I tried all kind of solutions to fix this (delete the page elements that are no longer active, using flags, etc) but nothing worked.

Thanks for you help

Comment: you remove the page after adding a product? if yes, then you have to unbind all `change` events upon leaving page-product on `pagehide` or `pagebeforehide` event. `$(document).on("pagehide", "#page_id", function () { $(document).off("change", "selectors"); }); });` because whenever the same page #page-product is initiated, it adds `change` listeners.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Omar however it don't seem to fix the issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: Another note, use `.on` not `.delegate`. There's no page called page-product?

Comment: `#page-product` exists, there is no difference in using `.on` or `.delegate` beside the arguments order so using `.on` is not fixing it either..

Comment: On pagehide try `$('selectors').off('change click')`

Comment: `$(document).off("change", "selectors");` was the right call but it didn't change anything. I've tried with `$('selectors').off('change click')` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was indeed unbinding the events (using `.off`), however `.off` is not working (at least for me) if you provide multiple selectors.

Example:

```
// This is NOT WORKING because multiple elements are used
$(document).off('change', '.class1, .class2, #idelement');

// This WORKS
$(document).off('change','#idelement');
$(document).off('change','.class1');
// and so on...

// You can add a class to all elements that you want to
// unbind, and then just call it once
$(document).off('event','.classForUnbind')

// If you want to unbind all elements
$(document).off('change');
```

Hope this helps